# how to create a link to a war file from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, war

I have a war file and I want to add it to another project and call it. how to create a link tag() to call it?

Comment: can you please elaborate what you want to do by *calling a war* ?

Comment: I have page (index.jsp) in a war file i want to go to that page from my application.

Comment: I got interested by the title. call war from jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to redirect to the `index.jsp` of "another war" running in a different context.

From your jsp, you can send a redirect to the location of the other index.jsp. For example:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/othercontext/index.jsp");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. A .war file is a web app in its own right, until it's deployed there ain't much you can do with it.  (As opposed to a .jar file, which contains classes you can use in other projects)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse some resources see [Weblets](https://github.com/werpu/weblets) project (formerly on java.net)